# ERROR: cannot find symbol when I compile a java class on command line..?

Tags: java

```js
public class Course {

  private String title;
  private String instructor;
  private double price;
  public enum CustomerType {
    PROGRAMMING, MATHEMATICS, PHOTOGRAPHY, MUSIC, PAINTING, MISC
  };
  private CourseType cType;
  private Date startDate;
  private Date endDate;

  public Course()
  {
    setTitle("");

    setInstructor("");
    setPrice(0.0);
    setCType("");
    setStartDate(new Date());
    setEndDate(new Date());
  }
  public Course(String title, String instructor, double price, Date startDate, Date endDate)
  {
    setTitle(title);
    setInstructor(instructor);
    setPrice(price);
    setStartDate(startDate);
    setEndDate(endDate);
  }

  public void setTitle(String title)
  {
    this.title = title;
  }

  public void setInstructor(String instructor)
  {
    this.instructor = instructor;
  }

  public void setPrice(double price)
  {
    this.price = price;
  }

  public void setCType(CourseType cType)
  {
    this.cType = cType;
  }

  public void setStartDate(Date startDate)
  {
    this.startDate = startDate;
  }

  public void setEndDate(Date endDate)
  {
    this.endDate = endDate;
  }

  public String getTitle()
  {
    return title;
  }

  public String getInstructor()
  {
    return instructor;
  }

  public double getPrice()
  {
    return price;
  }

  public CourseType getCType()
  {
    return cType;
  }

  public Date getStartDate()
  {
    return startDate;
  }

  public Date getEndDate()
  {
    return endDate;
  }

  public double calculateCharge(Customer.CustomerType c)
  {
    return 0.0;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    return ("title" + title + "instructor" + instructor + "price" + price + "cType" + cType);
  }
}
```

I tried checking spelling and formatting and couldn't find anything.

Here's three errors I keep getting when I compile:

error cannot find symbol
public CourseType getCTpe()

error cannot find symbol
public void setCType(CourseType cType)

error cannot find symbol
public CourseType cType;

Comment: Your enum is called `CustomerType` instead of `CourseType`.

Comment: Dude! I'd hug you if I knew where you lived! Lol I spent an hour pulling my hair trying to find the error. You're right! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need import statement in your class `Course` corresponding to `CourseType` class.

```
import fullyQualifiedPath.CourseType
```